# Why the geometric series diverges for x<=-1

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

The geometric series is defined as:

$$\frac{1}{1-x} = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + ...\tag{for $|x|<1$}$$
I know that for $x>=1$ it must diverge, of course. But I want some proof that it diverges when $x=1$ and $x<1$.

Comment: Write $1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + \cdots= 1+x^2+x^4+\cdots+x(1+x^2+x^4+\cdots)=(1+x)(1+x^2+x^4+\cdots)$

Comment: It’s a basic theorem that if $\sum_na_n$ converges, then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$. Clearly that’s not the case for $a_n=x^n$ if $x\le-1$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott but what can I say about the case $x=-1$? it's not clearly growing

Comment: @labbhattacharjee is this allowed to be done? I've seen that we may do these manipulations carefully because it leads to some wrong statements

Comment: @user108425, I think we can if $x\ne-1$

Comment: @user108425: So what? The only think that matters is that the terms are not converging to $0$. Alternatively, you can calculate the sequence of partial sums; it’s $\langle 1,0,1,0,\ldots\rangle$, which obviously does not converge, so the series must not converge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x=1$ then

$$1+x+x^2+...+x^n=1+1+..1+=n+1$$
which goes to infinity.

If $x=-1$ then 
$$1+x+..+x^n=\frac{(-1)^{n}+1}{2}$$
which doesn't converge.

If $x <-1$ then $\lim_n |x|^n=\infty$. This shows that $x^n$ doesn't go to $0$, which implies that the series is divergent.

Comment: @TedShifrin Ty, fixed.

Comment: When $x=-1$, how did you get the infinite series to be equal to $\frac{(-1)^n+1}{2}$?

Answer (score 2):

If $x=1$ or $x<-1$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty}x^n=$?

Added a different approach. If $x\ne1$ then
$$
1+x+\dots x^n=\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}.
$$

Comment: Yep but we're adding and subtracting, because the minus signal alternates, it's not clear that this will diverge

Comment: @user108425 A *necessary* condition for a series to converge is that the general term converges to $0$.

Comment: The first thing one usually learns about series is: If $\sum x_n$ converges, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=0$. So, if $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n\ne0$, then...

Answer (score 0):

Let $s_n$ denote the $n$th partial sum of the geometric series $1 + x + x^2 + \ldots + x^{n - 1}$ and suppose $x \neq 1$. Then we can write $(1-x)s_n = (1-x)(1 + x + x^2 + \ldots + x^{n - 1})$, the latter of which equals $1 - x^n$ by the telescoping property of finite sums. Dividing by $1 - x$ and decomposing the resultant fraction, we see that
$$s_n = \frac{1}{1-x} - \frac{x^n}{1-x}$$
If $|x| < 1$, then $x^n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ and the partial sums of the geometric series converge to $1/(1 - x)$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. This means that the geometric series converges to $1/(1-x)$ for $|x| < 1$.

Note that if $x = 1$, we see that each term of $s_n$ equals $1$, so that $s_n = n$. But then $s_n \rightarrow \infty$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, making the geometric series diverge when $x = 1$.

Finally, note that the decomposition of the partial sums of the geometric series given above provides the *reason* that convergence or divergence of the geometric series depends entirely on $x$, namely that the behavior of $s_n$ for arbitrarily large $n$ depends entirely on the behavior of $x^n$.

Answer (score 0):

If $x=-1$ the geometric series has sequence of partial sums $\{1, 0, 1, 0, \ldots \}$. The series converges if and only if the sequence of partial sums converges. But the sequence of partial sums diverges by oscillation.